# Why can't I create a fixed length tokyo cabinet database larger than 1.8GB?

Tags: database, memory, tokyo-cabinet

When I attempt to create a database using tcfdbtune with a parameter limsiz of 1900000000 (1.9GB) and then try to run a tcfdbopen, it fails with a "memory error", and I have no idea why.

When I create a 1.8 GB database, the process takes a lot of memory as well. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When use it with a "fixed length" DB

> the whole region of the database is mapped on memory by the `mmap' call

Seems that you are using a 32 bit version... see http://fallabs.com/tokyocabinet/spex-en.html

Comment: I would guess that you are right. I certainly had larger fixed indexes.